# swapon: Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, swap

I'm running this as root, obviously.

I've created a file called `/swap/sw1`, by dumping 512 megs of `/dev/zero` into it. I then ran `mkswap`, which said:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 524284 KiB
no label, UUID=f071fec6-0589-443f-9d46-1c126636418b
```

I'm assuming this means it worked fine. I've chmodded the file to 0600, and the file is owned by root. I then ran swapon:

```
$ swapon -v /swap/sw1
swapon on /swap/sw1
swapon: /swap/sw1: Operation not permitted
```

I've also tried adding this to fstab and calling `swapon -a -v`, but go the same problem. Why am I not allowed to use this file as a swap file?

One note, which I think is irrelevant but I could be wrong - I'm running on an OpenVZ VM.

Comment: Are you executing swapon as root?

Comment: @Kristof, configurator did state that he is running as root

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you were hit by the limitations of OpenVZ. OpenVZ does not allow what they call "user defined swap": Swap is only available "as a whole" for the whole system, not for individual VPSes, see http://forums.vpslink.com/linux/621-swap-space.html#post3915

Comment: Link appears to be broken.